# Why doesn't it show when I include an Expanded widget? It just does not show (when I replace it with a container for instance, it shows)

Tags: flutter

It's so weird, just does not work. The `BottomBar` widget is also wrapped in a `MaterialApp`, `Scaffold`, `SafeArea`, `Container`, `Stack`and `Positioned`.

I know, it's a long widget tree.

```
lass BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  BottomBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BottomBarState createState() => _BottomBarState();
}

class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 50,
              width: 100,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the width to the first Container in your BottomBar class. The width is necessary because when you use Expanded in BottomBar->Container->Row along with Positioned widget as the parent the incoming width constraints become unbounded. Please see the code below :

```
class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BottomBarState createState() => _BottomBarState();
}

class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 50,
              width: 100,
            ),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I request you to also like / up-vote the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks again.